# How to find the maximum and minimum date by key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$a = array(
           "2010-05-03" =>100,
          "2010-05-04" =>400,   
           "2008-05-01" =>800,
          "2011-01-01" =>800
     );
```

How do I find maximum and minimum by `key( date)`?

For example:

```
max => 2011-01-01
min => 2008-05-01
```

Comment: kn3l you been online in the last week.  The requirements expressed in your question do not align with your accepted answer.  This makes your question Unclear.  Please clarify this very old question because it will be confusing researchers and inviting answers that behave in fundamentally different ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would be lazy and just let PHP look twice over the array. Once to find the minimum and a second time to find the first matching key for that value:

```
$min_key = array_search(min($a), $a);
```

Or for the maximum:

```
$max_key = array_search(max($a), $a);
```

Comment: `max()` and `min()` return the highest/lowest value of an array, not the highest/lowest key.

Comment: Yes, that's what they do. Hence the second step.

Comment: Arg, stupid me thought `array_search()` returns a value, not a key ... but that does not make any sense. Sorry! :-)

Comment: you're getting the max and min of strings not date time objects !

Comment: There are no datetime objects on this page.  I do, however, find the asked question and the accepted answer to be at odds.

Answer (score 5):

(Not sure if you want the values for the max and min keys or the keys for the max and min values.)

This returns the values for the max/min keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($a);
$min = $a[min($keys));
$max = $a[max($keys));
```

Comment: On second reading, this might be what OP actually asked for. (Finding minimum/maximum dates.)

Answer (score 2):

```
$maxK = $a[0];
$minK = $a[0];
foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    if($v > $a[$maxK]) $maxK = $v;
    if($v < $a[$minK]) $minK = $v;
}
```

Is probably what you want. Then you can get the min/max keys and values like so:

```
$maxKey = $maxK;
$maxValue = $a[$maxK];
$minKey = $minK;
$minValue = $a[$minK];
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to extract the keys from the array via [array_keys](http://www.php.net/array_keys) and then natural case sort the keys via [natcasesort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php).

As such, you'd end up with:

```
<?php
    $testData = array(
        "2010-05-03" =>100,
        "2010-05-04" =>400,   
        "2008-05-01" =>800,
        "2011-01-01" =>800
    );

    natcasesort($testKeys = array_keys($testData));

    echo 'Min: ' . $testKeys[0] . ', max: ' . $testKeys[count($testKeys) - 1] . '<br />';
?>
```

Comment: `Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference` from PHP7.4 and below.  From above PHP8, `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: natcasesort(): Argument #1 ($array) cannot be passed by reference`  Why does this array of values without any letters in the keys need `natcasesort()`?  ...hint, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
asort($a);
$keys = array_keys($a);
$min = $keys[0];
$max = $keys[count($keys) - 1];
```

or, simply

```
$min = array_search(min($a), $a);
$max = array_search(max($a), $a);
```