# PHP: Parse from an array the oldest date

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, datetime

I have this array:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(2) {
        ["url"]=> string(104) "aHR0cDovL3lvdXR1YmUuY29t"
        ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-01-06 21:44:39" 
     }

    [1]=> array(2) { 
        ["url"]=> string(28) "aHR0cDovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29t"
        ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-01-06 14:28:32"
     }
 }
```

How can I parse the `$row['date']` for the earliest date?

Comment: Well, you can sort it and then get the first/last element

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the maximum and minimum date by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888925/how-to-find-the-maximum-and-minimum-date-by-key)

Comment: Are you getting this array from a database? You can change up the query (`ORDER BY date ASC` if you're in MySQL) to automatically give you sorted results, oldest date first.

Comment: @Esaevian Nop it is not from a database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can do this using `array_map` and `min` functions:

```
function customFunction($array) {
  return $array['date'];
}
$dateArray= array_map('customFunction', $array);
```

So, you have an array with your dates, after just do:

```
$oldDate = min($dateArray); //here you get the oldest date
```

Comment: Thank you. This work perfectly. Is it possible I can make minus 1 second from the $oldate?

Comment: Yes, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885098/subtract-one-second-from-a-given-time, hope it help you

Comment: @jQuerybeast I think [`DateTime::sub`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

To find the min date in array try this code

```
 $minDate = min(array_map(function($item) { return $item['date']; }, $array));
```

Comment: How can I make this minus 1 second?

Comment: echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($minDate) - 1)

Comment: If nulls are messing up your `min()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23565246/470749

Answer (score 1):

Something simple like this should do

```
$earliest_date = date_create();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $date = date_create($row['date']);
    if($date < $earliest_date)
        $earliest_date = $date;
}
```