# Select earliest date of future dates in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MSQL column structure. How do I select the earliest date of future dates and ignore the past ones.

start_date

```
2018-07-01 -> past
2018-07-07 -> past
2018-07-14 -> future (SELECT THIS ONE ONLY, the earliest of the future ones)
2018-07-18 -> future
2018-07-22 -> future
```

Please help. I'm struggling with this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: is past and future values of another field ? what is the column name in that case ?

Comment: @uemit please check my answer. if it works for you; please accept it.

Comment: @JeffUK Sorry for not mentioning. I did it in two steps, first: SELECT * FROM `agenda` WHERE (start_date >= CURDATE()) which delivers me all future dates. And then in PHP I did it like described [PHP: Parse from an array the oldest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958708/php-parse-from-an-array-the-oldest-date ). Which kind of works, but I need it to be done in MYSQL directly in one step and get one row only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previous version of this answer was *non-performant* , especially on large tables. It was not using any index whatsoever. Here is a better approach:

```sql
SELECT DATE(start_date)
FROM your_table_name
WHERE start_date >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY
ORDER BY start_date ASC
LIMIT 1
```

- This can utilise an index on `start_date` column.
- It short-circuits using `LIMIT 1` , as soon as the result is found.

---

Previous version (**don't use**):

<s>Try this:</s>

```
SELECT MIN(DATE(start_date)) 
FROM table 
WHERE DATE(start_date) > DATE(NOW())
```

1. [NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function gives you the current date. So we search for only those dates, which are more than current date.
2. Out of the searched dates, we get the minimum (earliest) date using [MIN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) function.
3. [DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function extracts the date part out of a date/datetime expression (eg: result of [NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)) to **yyyy-mm-dd** format (eg: `'2018-07-27'`).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much, that did it!